Предупреждение A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame при преобразовании колонки из строки в дату
Есть Dataframe одна из колонок Time содержит время в строчном формате.
3            2017.01.09 00:00:28
4            2017.01.09 00:00:28
5            2017.01.09 10:17:58
6            2017.01.09 10:17:58
7            2017.01.09 12:02:27

Нужно преобразовать в формат datetime. Во всех статьях дают вариант:
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], format='%Y.%m.%d  %H:%M:%S')

При выполнение возникает Предупреждение:
SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

Как преобразовать в DataFrame одну колонку без такого предупреждения

Скорее всего это так называемая "наведённая ошибка", то есть ошибка, возникшая из-за чего-то, что было раньше. Вангую, что df - это не исходный датафрейм, а полученный из другого датафрейма каким-то не очень корректным способом (например, выборкой по условию, без использования .loc). Починить это по-быстрому можно скорее всего сделав df = df.copy() перед строкой, где возникает ошибка.
